# How to make the following jQuery snippet work?

Tags: jquery, this

```
var func = function()
{
    $(this).hide();
    $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.removeClass('my_signature_mouseover');
    var text = $(this).val();
    var $span = $("#status span");
    $span.text(text);
    $span.show();
};
$("#status input").keyup(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 13) {
       func();
    }
}).blur(func);
```

I want to make `func` run if blur or pressing "Enter" on it.
But the above code works only when blur,
in the case of pressing "Enter",it reports "Permission denied to access parentNode".

Although I know it's something related with `this` keyword in different context,I've no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `func`, with a normal function call, that causes inside `func`, the `this` variable will refer to the global object (window).

You have to execute the function with [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:Function:call), in order to preserve the context (the `'this'` value), which is the element that triggered the event:

```
$("#status input").keyup(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 13) {
       e.preventDefault(); // stop event propagation
       func.call(this);
    }
}).blur(func);
```

Comment: It's near.But I've called $(this).select() first,and after pressing "Enter",the value of input is cleared,how to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Not working,I guess the keyup function get called after the default behaviour.

Comment: I need more details, could you post a detailed example on http://jsbin.com exposing the wrong behavior that you are experiencing?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var func = function(elem)
{
    elem.hide();
    var $parent = elem.parent();
    $parent.removeClass('my_signature_mouseover');
    var text = elem.val();
    var $span = $("#status span");
    $span.text(text);
    $span.show();
};
$("#status input").keyup(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 13) {
       func($(this));
    }
}).blur(function () {
    func($(this));
});
```